# What is an slack of an edge in Graph Theory? And why does the slack of an edge need to be zero for shortest path trees?

Tags: math, tree, computer-science, graph-theory

I understand the formula for a slack but can anyone explain in normal terms and what it signifies in the big picture? Also, why does the slack of an edge need to be zero for shortest path trees?

Comment: The term "slackness" arises primarily from linear programming and its meaning varies by context. Which specific slackness formula are you referencing? Can you give us some more context?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, slack is just "unused capacity".  If you have a maximal flow on an edge, and the actual flow over an edge for some configuration, the slack is the difference.